# R: Converting "tables" to "data frame: 'height' must be a vector or a matrix

Tags: r, plot, graph, data-visualization, data-manipulation

I found the following code in R that plots a histogram and colors some of the bars red:

```
n = floor(rnorm(10000, 500, 100))
t = table(n)

# get color counts
r <- floor(length(t)/2)
b <- length(t) - r

# repeat red r times, repeat black b times
barplot(t, col = rep(c("red", "black"), c(r, b)), border = NA)

# use "topleft" to place legend
legend("topleft", legend=c("group a", "group b"),
       col=c("red", "black"), lty = 1, cex=0.8)
title(main = "some title", 
      sub = "some title")
```

[image]

As seen in the above code, this requires that the data be in the "table" format.

****Question:**** I am trying to make the same graph, but use "data frames" instead. This will allow me more flexibility (e.g. assign colors randomly to bars in the histogram) as I am more familiar with data frames. I tried to write the following code:

```
#randomly assign colors to different bars in the histogram and convert table into data frame

color <- c("red", "black")     
color_1 <- as.factor(sample(color, 10000, replace=TRUE, prob=c(0.5, 0.5)))
t = data.frame(t)
t$color_1 <-color_1
barplot(t, color = t$color_1)
```

But this returns several errors:

```
Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, color_1, value = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L,  : 
  replacement has 10000 rows, data has 574
```

For some reason, the data has 583 rows instead of the 10,000 originally specified in (**where did all the rows go!?**) `n = floor(rnorm(10000, 500, 100))` command.

Ignoring this, if I do assume 583 rows:

```
color <- c("red", "black")     
color_1 <- as.factor(sample(color, 574, replace=TRUE, prob=c(0.5, 0.5)))
t = data.frame(t)
t$color_1 <-color_1
barplot(t, color = t$color_1)
```

I get a new error:

```
Error in barplot.default(t, color = t$color_1) : 
  'height' must be a vector or a matrix
```

Can someone please show me how to fix this error?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the formula method for `data.frame`

```
t <- as.data.frame(t)
color <- c("red", "black")     
color_1 <- sample(color, nrow(t), replace=TRUE, prob=c(0.5, 0.5))
barplot(Freq ~ n, data = t, col = color_1, border = NA)
```

-output

[image]

Comment: thank you for your answer! one of the biggest mysteries for me:

Comment: n = floor(rnorm(1000, 500, 100))
t = table(n)

t <- as.data.frame(t)

Comment: why doesnt "t" have 1000 rows?

Comment: @Noob because `table` is having a length of only 585 or so.  It creates a named vector of frequency, thus there is only one unique name and its frequency  `t = table(n);
 length(t)
[1] 585`

Comment: @Noob If you want to have 1000 rows, then some observations will be duplciated i.e. `tibble(n1 = n) %>% add_count(n1)`

Comment: Thank you for your reply! When I try to convert the tibble into a dataframe: n2 = data.frame(tibble(n1 = n) %>% add_count(n1))

Comment: Then try to plot the graph: > color <- c("red", "black")     
> color_1 <- sample(color, nrow(n2), replace=TRUE, prob=c(0.5, 0.5))
> barplot(n ~ n1, data = n2, col = color_1, border = NA)

Comment: @Noob you don't really need to cnovert to data.frame as `tibble` can also work.

Comment: I got the following error: Error in barplot.formula(n ~ n1, data = n2, col = color_1, border = NA) : 
  duplicated categorical values - try another formula or subset

Comment: @Noob But, the one I showed will have duplicate observations for 'n1' and this is not desired and that is the reason I said to use `table` or `count` which summarised the output.  You can check on a simple example `v1 <- c(1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4); t1 <- table(v1); barplot(t1)`

Comment: `table` gives the frequency count of each unique observations in 'v1' i.e. for 1, it gives 2 as count, 4, it shows 3 as count with the unique values as names attribute